# Embed not sending discord js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

For some reason this code below is not sending a embed to the reports channel tried what i could to fix it it will not send tried client.channels.cache.get(Channel).send(embed); that gave me a error tried it multipole ways and it still won't send

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'report',
    usage: '%report <reason>',
    description: 'reports a person',

    async execute(client, message, args) {
        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || await message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])

        if (!user) return message.reply(`Please mention a user to report`)

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if (!reason) return message.reply(`Please enter a reason`)

        let Avatar = user.displayAvatarURL();
        let Channel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == 'reports')
        if (!Channel) return message.reply(`Thier is no Valid channel to send a report please contact a staff member`)

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('New Report')
            .setDescription(`The member ${message.author.tag} has reported ${user.tag}`)
            .setColor("RED")
            .setThumbnail(Avatar)
            .addFields({
                name: "Member ID,",
                value: `${message.author.id}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: "Member Tag,",
                value: `${message.author.tag}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: "Reported ID,",
                value: `${user.id}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: "Reported Tag,",
                value: `${user.tag}`,
                inline: true
            }, {
                name: "Reason,",
                value: `${reason}`,
                inline: true
            })



        client.channels.cache.get(Channel);
        message.channel.send(`Successfully sent the report!`)
    }
}

function findChannel(client, channelName) {
    var channelId = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(channelName.toLowerCase())).id;
}
```

Comment: Try `Channel.send(embed)`.  If that doesn't work, what specific errors is it giving you?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
let Channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == 'reports')

if (!Channel) return message.reply(`Thier is no Valid channel to send a report please contact a staff member`)

Channel.send(embed)

message.channel.send(`Successfully sent the report!`)
```

Comment: The grammar was on the author's part. I only copied his code and made changes to it. I did not change his strings.